# Making an Enum more flexible in pydantic

Tags: python, pydantic

In the following model

```py
from pydantic import (BaseModel, validator)
from enum import Enum

class City(str, Enum):
    new_york = "New York"
    los_angeles = "Los Angeles"

class CityData(BaseModel):
    city:City
    population:int
```

One can construct instances of `CityData` as

```py
c = CityData(city="New York", population=8419000)
```

I would like to be able to create the same instance with

```py
c = CityData(city="NY", population=8419000)
```

**Question:** How to do this?

Adding a validator to `CityData`, like

```py
@validator("city")
def _flexible_city(cls, v, values, *kwargs):
    if v == "NY":
        return "New York"
    else:
        return v
```

doesn't work. It looks like the value `v` is already an instance of `City`. Does that mean that the conversion should happen in the constructor of `City`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In such cases, it is convenient to use a [pre-validator](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/validators/#pre-and-per-item-validators) that is called prior to parsing and other validations.

```
class CityData(BaseModel):
    city: City
    population: int

    @validator("city", pre=True)
    def _flexible_city(cls, v):
        if v == "NY":
            return "New York"
        else:
            return v
```

Comment: Interesting. Besides the semantic differences with [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66656616/14176811) and the fact that one is in the `CityBank` class while the other is in the `City` class, do you see some advantages or disadvantages between them?

Comment: It seems to me that validators are more flexible and universal way. I would use them, leaving the enumeration clean. But this is only if you are using pydantic

Answer (score 2):

I think I found the way to do it using the [`_missing_`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#supported-sunder-names) method of `City`

```py
class City(str,Enum):
    new_york = "New York"
    los_angeles = "Los Angeles"
    @classmethod
    def _missing_(cls, name):
        if name == "NY":
            return cls.new_york
        else:
            return cls[name]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try `autoenum`, which adds this functionality to Pydantic. The `alias` feature allows you specify other names for an enum.

Repo: https://github.com/adivekar-utexas/autoenum/ (Disclaimer: I am the author).

Example:

```
from autoenum import AutoEnum, auto, alias
class City(AutoEnum):
    Atlanta = auto()
    Boston = auto()
    New_York_City = alias('New York', 'NYC')
    Washington = alias('Washington D.C.')

from pydantic import BaseModel, conint, confloat, constr
class Company(BaseModel):
    name: constr(min_length=1)
    headquarters: City   ## AutoEnum 
    num_employees: conint(ge=1)
```

Usage:

```
>>> jp_morgan = Company(name='JPMorgan Chase', headquarters='NYC', num_employees=308_000)
>>> jp_morgan.json()
'{"name": "JPMorgan Chase", "headquarters": "New_York_City", "num_employees": 308000}'
```